# zoomable Köppen climate maps

Tags: maps, mountains

So I recently hiked Humphrey's Peak in Arizona and was curious if I passed through multiple different Köppen climate types.

Quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Arizona#Humphreys_Peak , "*Towards the top of the trail Humphreys Peak contains the only area of subarctic tundra south of the Rocky Mountains*". I'm assuming subarctic tundra is a reference to the Köppen climate type, which makes me wonder what other Köppen climate type I hiked through.

For Arizona there's a map at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Arizona#/media/File:Arizona_K%C3%B6ppen.svg but it's of limited resolution and you can't really search by latitude / longitude on that map. And, more generally, it'd be cool to have a map of the entire US (or entire world lol) vs a map of a single state!

Comment: Climate maps probably don't exist at such a high resolution, or if they do, they're not reliable.  You may have better luck with a high scale vegetation map, which is much easier to construct from remote sensing data and is a pretty good proxy for climate.  For example, for the Swedish mountains there are [1:100k vegetation maps](http://www.peterandren.se/SweVegMap/swevegmap_swe.php) — maybe USGS or state offices have produced something similar for Arizona or the US.

Comment: Incidentally, the line you quoted is odd: firstly, for a north-south range to speak of "south of" is a little odd.  Secondly, it would be mountain tundra, not subarctic tundra.  Thirdly, there is certainly mountain tundra in the Andes, which is south of anywhere in the USA.